# reading a list using Get method on external API (REST)(java)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Im trying to learn how to consume a REST webservice using Jersey. Im using a get request to view data from the URI "https://api.fixer.io/latest" this URI displays a base, date and i believe a array/ArrayList. In my class below, i have managed to display the date and base of the resource. But I am having trouble displaying the list of items. When i run my code it gives this:

Date = 2017-12-15, base = EURlist = []

an example of what im looking for would be:

Date = 2017-12-15, base = EUR list = [AUD":1.5382,"BGN":1.9558 (etc)]

Here is my code: 
restServiceClient.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;

public class restServiceClient{


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Exchange exchange = client.target("https://api.fixer.io/latest")
                      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                      .get(Exchange.class);


String base = exchange.getBase();
String date = exchange.getDate();
ArrayList<String> theList = exchange.getRates();

//String[] excArray = theList.toArray();
System.out.print(exchange);

client.close() ;
}

}
```

Exchange.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class Exchange {
    private String base;
    private String date;
    private ArrayList<String> rates;

    public ArrayList<String> getRates() {
        return rates;
    }

    public void setRates(ArrayList<String> rates) {
        this.rates = rates;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }



    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }



  @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Date = " + date + ", base = "
            + base + " list = " + rates;
}

}
```

Comment: What happens if you specify a `MediaType` of JSON instead of XML ?

Comment: @MikeNakis Hi Mike, just the exact same thing

Comment: First, program on interfaces (List, not ArrayList). Second, look at the response: https://api.fixer.io/latest/ It's JSON, not XML. So don't request XML. Third, as you see, rates is not a list of Strings. It's an array of objects with a key of type String, and a value of type number. This would typically mapped by a JSON mapper as a Map<String, Double>, not as an ArrayList<String>.

Comment: @JBNizet Perfect response thank you. Have yet to read over Map so was unaware of this! I have changed my code to follow your guidance and now have the desired result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, program on interfaces (`List`, not `ArrayList`).

Second, look at the response at https://api.fixer.io/latest. It's JSON, not XML. So don't request XML.

Third, as you see, rates is not a list of Strings. It's an array of objects with a key of type String, and a value of type number. This would typically mapped by a JSON mapper as a `Map<String, Double>`, not as an `ArrayList<String>`.